# Dropbox API Sharing URL - IE-Only Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, dropbox, dropbox-api

When I use the Dropbox API to get a shared link, it works just fine in Chrome and shows a preview.

In IE (IE 11/Win 8.1), it shows the blue and white Dropbox header then, instead of previewing the document, it asks (in a fairly ugly way) for a password to open some PDF - notice that this is NOT a PDF, nor does the DOCX have a password.  I *assume* that the PDF in question is the preview.

Replacing the **dl=0** at the end with **dl=1** downloads the file in either browser but I'd really like to use the Dropbox preview feature, if possible.

At the moment, I'm thinking that it's a Dropbox issue more than a Dropbox API issue.  I'm not sure why Dropbox would have a preview option that doesn't work in the latest version of IE.

I hope it doesn't matter but I am **not** logged into Dropbox in the browser, nor do I expect/require my users to be.

Thanks!

Comment: Tried in Win 8.1/IE 11, works just fine. It might be something up to your IE 11 instance. Do you see some error in browser console? Can you share screenshot?

Comment: Hmm, good call on the Console error:

SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
File: viewer-vflR5jnGX.html, Line: 1, Column: 1

Of course, that's not my script, it's Dropbox's.  

Screenshot at https://www.dropbox.com/s/s3bdsv98v127wwz/screenshot.png?dl=0.  Interesting that THAT link works for me - I guess because it's not being converted to a PDF for preview by Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Update: If I tell IE to use Compatability view for Dropbox.com, it works just fine.

Not pretty but close enough!